# TeamViewer Unattended Access without Monitor

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, remote-desktop, remote-access, teamviewer

I'm trying to manage some computers on my LAN. I don't have a windows pro version to get to other machines. If I don't have a monitor plugged in to the computers I want to manage, will remote support still work?

I'd also be interested to know how other remote support applications behave, such as TightVNC, RealVNC, or remote desktop.

I have machines running, Windows 7 and Windows 8.1.

Comment: I regularly access an XP system on my LAN using both TeamViewer and UltraVNC. It has a monitor, but it is usually turned off when I gain access. This is not quite the same as having no monitor, but it suggests that all will be OK without a monitor, provided that the OS will boot. I also use TeamViewer on a MediaPC running Windows 7, which outputs HDMI graphics to a television, but with the television either switched off or taking input from a different HDMI port (again, not quite the same as no monitor, but encouraging).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you still will be able to use teamviewer, but teamviewer might not be able to use a resolution other than 800x600. I used to use Linux with Teamviewer on it, and if I booted the OS without the monitor being on (which was most of the time) it would report as no monitor present, and defaulted to 800x600.

Windows might remember the resolution last used even with no monitor present, but I'm not exactly sure.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it on my Windows 8.1 machine and the iPhone app. Windows did remember the resolution of the last monitor I had plugged in. If you want to do this, plug in the highest resolution monitor you can to make sure TeamViewer is set to start automatically and so you can have the highest resolution you can.

One thing to note is that in the Windows screen resolution settings (over TeamViewer with no monitor attached) the resolution dropdown menu was grayed out.